# About Selling the bitcoins for normal person

Tags: exchanges, sell-bitcoins, paypal

It's Aashish Sharma from Nepal. I have been mining bitcoins online for a few months. I want to, if I can, sell them online for cash or USD into my PayPal account. I don't know what can I do for few bitcoins. Or can I do normal online shopping with those few coins? Help me out.

Comment: In the Netherlands we got https://bitonic.nl/, where you can send them Bitcoins and they send the value (minus transaction costs) in euro (local currency) on your bank account. Maybe something similar exist in Nepal. But make sure you can trust the company. Just out of curiosity, how have you mine them? With ASIC/FPGA/GPU/CPU? Did you make any profit after subtracting the power cost?

Answer (score 1):

In the Philippines we have "coins.ph". I can easily transfer bitcoins to my bitcoin wallet at coins.ph then convert it to my local currency that is available for withdrawal on banks and remittance center. You should look for similar website that supports your local currency